# How to jump image on touch

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android Studio, I need help.
Here is my ImageView layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/launcher"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical ="true"/>
```

I want to jump image when I touch on the image..

I have the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
        {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            dx = x-myView.getX();
            dy = y-myView.getY();
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        {
            myView.setX(event.getX()-dx);
            myView.setY(event.getY()-dy);
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
        {
            //your stuff
        }
    return true;
}
```

Please help me, what will be the proper code?

Comment: What do you mean by "jump"?

Comment: Do you want to move the image by dragging across the image? Or do you want the image to jump to a location on the screen you touch? Please clarify.

Comment: yes, i want to do this, can u help me. #skbrhmn